# todos TypeError cannot read property undefined

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, crud

I made todo list as project but apparently I made an error which I can't fix can anyone help me with this thank you.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Todoitem from './Todoitem';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Todos extends Component {
    render(){
        return this.PropTypes.todos.map(todo =>
            <Todoitem
                key={todo.id}
                todo={todo}
                markComplete={this.PropTypes.markComplete}
                delTodo={this.PropTypes.delTodo}
            />);
    };
};

// PropTypes
Todos.propTypes = {
    todos: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default Todos;
```

I also include actual error for further info :

[image: I also include actual error for further info]

Answer (score 0):

You want `this.props.todos`, not `this.propTypes.todos`.

Proptypes are only something you define so that React can help catch mistakes you make; you don't actually reference them in your React code.  `this.props`, on the other hand, is an object containing all of the key/value pairs from the component's tag's attributes.

Comment: when I change the propTypes to props the error change to this:
Line 11:42:  'markComplete' is missing in props validation
and it says failed to compile

Comment: That means that wherever you are *using* this component, you aren't passing a `markComplete` prop.  In other words, you have `<Todos/>` **not** `<Todos markComplete={true} />`.  You may wish to review https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html